# SHGetFolderPath returns incorrect file path for non-English Windows

Tags: visual-c++, appdata, mbcs

My application uses SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath) to get the file path for application data. A user reported (via a Survey Monkey survey) a bug as reported below --

"Win XP uses partly a Czech name "C:\Documents and Settings\%my profile%\Data aplikací" The letter í (i with acute) causes a problem: The library.db file cannot be found since the program searches "Data aplikac" instead of the correct "Data aplikací" as I have seen in the File Monitor."

How do I rectify this problem? It is difficult for me to debug the problem without a Czech user I can communicate with.

The application is compiled for MBCS not Unicode.

Comment: `í` aka `U+00ED` is representable in both Western European (cp1252) and Eastern European (cp1250) codepages. So, either the system is configured with yet another codepage in which `í` is not representable (and then any MBCS application is kind of screwed; but that sounds unlikely for a system used primarily by a Czech user), or your code does some filtering of its own and discards all non-ASCII characters (in which case, just don't). In any case, the ultimate solution is to build a Unicode build.

Comment: I am not filtering. This is my code which is super simple. 

TCHAR szPath[MAX_PATH];
if (SUCCEEDED(SHGetFolderPath(NULL, CSIDL_APPDATA, NULL, 0, szPath))) 
 m_sAppDataPath  = szPath; 
 
I will turn off the functionality for the feature requiring this path if the path can't be found. Converting to unicode is a major expense for this rather minor issue.